# Mismatched types with propositional logic implementation in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, syntax, pattern-matching, logic

I'm trying to implement propositional logic in haskell with the following code:

```
module Propositional_Logic where

--Syntax
--It will be considered three logical values.
data Logical_value = TRUE | FALSE | INDETERMINATE deriving (Show, Eq)
--A propositional symbol (variable) is a string.
type Propositional_symbol = String 
--Four basics logicals connectives.
data Propositional_connective = And 
                              | Or 
                              | Impl 
                              | Dimpl 
                              deriving (Show, Eq)
--A well-formed formula (propositional expression) can be a logical value, a propositional symbol, the negation of a well-formed formula, two well-formed formulas connected by a logical connective and the conjunction or disjunction of well-formed formulas.
data Propositional_expression = Logical_value
                              | Propositional_symbol
                              | Neg Propositional_expression
                              | Propositional_expression Propositional_connective Propositional_expression
                              | Propositional_connective [Propositional_expression] -- Semantic will throw error if connective is not And or Or.
                              deriving (Show, Eq)

--Semantic
--Type to assign logical values to propositional symbols.
type Interpretation = Propositional_symbol -> Logical_value

interpretationInit :: Interpretation
interpretationInit _ = INDETERMINATE

--Function to add interpretations for basic propositional symbols.
update :: Interpretation -> Interpretation -> Interpretation
update i1 i2 = (\x -> if i2 x == INDETERMINATE then i2 x else i1 x)

--Function to obtain the logical value from a propositional expression and the interpretation from basic propositional variables.
interpretation :: Propositional_expression -> Interpretation -> Logical_value
--Logical Values
interpretation (TRUE) i = TRUE
interpretation (FALSE) i = FALSE
interpretation (INDETERMINATE) i = INDETERMINATE
```

I'm having the following compiling error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Propositional_Logic ( propositional_logic.hs, interpreted )

propositional_logic.hs:36:21:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Propositional_expression’
            with actual type ‘Logical_value’
In the pattern: TRUE
In an equation for ‘interpretation’: interpretation (TRUE) i = TRUE

propositional_logic.hs:37:21:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Propositional_expression’
            with actual type ‘Logical_value’
In the pattern: FALSE
In an equation for ‘interpretation’:
    interpretation (FALSE) i = FALSE

propositional_logic.hs:38:21:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Propositional_expression’
            with actual type ‘Logical_value’
In the pattern: INDETERMINATE
In an equation for ‘interpretation’:
    interpretation (INDETERMINATE) i = INDETERMINATE
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I think my syntax is correct: if a propositional_expression can be a Logical_value I expected Haskell matches it correctly but it must be something I'm missing. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Not really relevant: double check your `update` function -- it looks wrong to me, since the then branch always returns `INDETERMINATE`.

Comment: Note that there was a rather blatant mistake in the code within my answer as I originally wrote it. If you were left wondering why it didn't work, check the updated version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are mixing up `Logical_value`, the *type* with constructors `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `INDETERMINATE`, and `Logical_value`, the *constructor* of the `Propositional_expression` type. The fact that you are using the same names throughout is obscuring quite a few distinctions and issues. For one, the `Logical_value` case of `Propositional_expression` doesn't actually contain a `Logical_value`, as it is just an atomic value. What follows is an adjustment of your types so that they have clearer names and behave in the way you want them to:

```
-- I'm changing the names to CamelCase out of habit -- feel free not to. 

-- It will be considered three logical values.
data LogicalValue = TRUE | FALSE | INDETERMINATE deriving (Show, Eq)

-- A propositional symbol (variable) is a string.
type PropositionalSymbol = String 

-- Four basics logicals connectives.
data PropositionalConnective
    = And 
    | Or 
    | Impl 
    | Dimpl 
    deriving (Show, Eq)

-- A well-formed formula (propositional expression) can be a logical
-- value, a propositional symbol, the negation of a well-formed formula,
-- two well-formed formulas connected by a logical connective and the 
-- conjunction or disjunction of well-formed formulas.
data PropositionalExpression 
    = ValueExpr LogicalValue
    | SymbolExpr PropositionalSymbol
    | NegExpr PropositionalExpression
    | ConnectiveExpr
        PropositionalExpression PropositionalConnective PropositionalExpression
    | ListExpr PropositionalConnective [PropositionalExpression] 
        -- Semantic will throw error if connective is not And or Or.
    deriving (Show, Eq)

-- Semantic
-- Type to assign logical values to propositional symbols.
type Interpretation = PropositionalSymbol -> LogicalValue
```

And here is how `interpretation` would look like. Note how the constructors (`ValueExpr`, `SymbolExpr`, etc.) are used to pick the case that each equation handles. That is what lies behind your type error -- `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `INDETERMINATE` are not constructors of `PropositionalExpression`, neither in your original code nor in my modified version (by the way, you were right in suspecting it wasn't a syntax error: the syntax in your original code was legal, but it didn't do what you expected, leading to a type error).

```
-- Function to obtain the logical value from a propositional expression
-- and the interpretation from basic propositional variables.
interpretation :: PropositionalExpression -> Interpretation -> LogicalValue
-- Logical Values
-- All three cases here can be subsumed into one.
-- _ simply means "ignore this argument".
interpretation (ValueExpr x) _ = x
-- And so forth for the other PropositionalExpression cases
```